# Inverting the binomial convolution of sequences

Tags: combinatorics

let $\left \{ a_{n} \right \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $\left \{ b_{n} \right \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ be two sequences. The binomial convolution of the two sequences is given by : 
$$\left(a\star b\right)_{n}=c_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}a_{k}b_{n-k}$$ 
Is there a way to recover $a_{n}b_{n}$ via something akin to :
$$a_{n}b_{n}=\sum_{k=0}^{n}d_{n,k}c_{k}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let

- $a_n=1$,
- $b_n=1$,
- $\tilde a_n=2^n$, and
- $\tilde b_0=1$, $\tilde b_n=0$ for all $n>0$.

Note that $$a_n\star b_n=\tilde a_n\star \tilde b_n=2^n$$ have the same binomial convolution, but $$a_nb_n=1\neq \tilde b_n=\tilde a_n\tilde b_n.$$ Therefore, the binomial convolution is insufficient to recover the Hadamard product.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: this does not answer the question (see comments.)

Let $X$ be the space of all (real or complex) sequences $a=\{a_n\}_0^\infty$ and define $T\colon X\to X$ as
$$
(Ta)_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}a_k.
$$
What you are asking is if $a$ can be recovered from $Ta$. The answer is yes, and it can be done recursively. First of all, it is clear that $a_0=(Ta)_0$. Now, if $a_0,\dots,a_{n-1}$ have been found, we have
$$
a_n=(Ta)_n-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}a_k.
$$

Comment: I think you misread the definition of $\star$ as $(a\star b)_n=\sum_k \binom{n}k a_kb_k$, because your $T$ operator is unrelated to $\sum_k \binom{n}k a_k b_{n-k}$.

Comment: I see. I read $a_kb_k$ instead of $a_kb_{n-k}$.

Answer (score 1):

Given
$$
c_{\,n}  = \,\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\binom{n}{k}  a_{\,k} \,b_{\,n - k} } 
$$
then notice that the e.g.f.'s are in the following relation
$$
\eqalign{
  & C(z) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n\,} {{{c_{\,n} } \over {n!}}\,z^{\,n} }
  = \,\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n\,} {{1 \over {n!}}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\binom{n}{k}
a_{\,k} \,b_{\,n - k} \,z^{\,n} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \,\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n\,} {{1 \over {n!}}\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\binom{n}{k}
 a_{\,k} z^{\,k} \,b_{\,n - k} z^{\,n - k} \,} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \,\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n\,} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {{{a_{\,k} } \over {k!}}z^{\,k}
  \,{{b_{\,n - k} } \over {\left( {n - k} \right)!}}z^{\,n - k} \,} }  =   \cr 
  &  = \,\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n\,} {{{a_{\,k} } \over {k!}}z^{\,k} } } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j\,} {\,{{b_{\,j} } \over {j!}}z^{\,j} \,} } \right) =   \cr 
  &  = \,A(z)B(z) \cr} 
$$

That premised, and passing for simplicity to the ordinary g.f.
$$
C(z) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n\,} {c_{\,n} \,z^{\,n} }
  = \,\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n\,} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,k\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {a_{\,k} \,b_{\,n - k} \,z^{\,n} } }  = A(z)B(z)
$$
if I understand properly your question and comment, you need to compute $D(z)$
$$
D(z) = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,n\,} {a_{\,n} b_{\,n} \,z^{\,n} } 
$$
knowing $A(z)$ and $B(z)$ .

Then, assuming that these are convergent in a domain of non-null measure, you can use the 
duality of the Convolution Theorem , same as for the Fourier series, which for the z-Transform 
reads as
$$
D(z) = {1 \over {i2\pi }}\oint\limits_C {A(z)B(z/v){{dv} \over v}} 
$$
refer to last entry of the table in this [Wikipedia Article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-transform#Properties)

Comment: yes, i am aware of that. what i am seeking, though, is the Hadamard product of the OGFs of the two sequences, as opposed to the direct product of the EGFs. my question translates to : how to obtain the Hadamard product of the OGFs of the two sequences from $A(z)B(z)$ ?

Comment: @MohammadAlJamal: added possible solution: don't know if I caught exactly your question

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} a_k b_{n-k} = \frac{1}{n!} (A \ast B)(n)$ where $\ast$ is the usual convolution and $A_n = a_n n! ,B_n = b_n n!$. So in general you can't recover $A B$ only from $A \ast B$ as if $u \ast v = 1_{n=0}$ then replacing $A,B$ by $A \ast u, B \ast v$ doesn't change $A \ast B$ but changes $AB$ @MohammadAlJamal